# Resuming IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice

Is there any way how to restart my `IntentService`? I´ve found out, that when my application is minimized, everything´s ok, but when the system is overloaded (f.ex. there is incoming call and at the same time, message is delivered, etc..), the systems stops my application (current activity). But the problem is in `IntentService` - it is stopped too, and I need that to work all the time.

Android documentation says:
'The service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.'
I created my `IntentService` according to what the documentation says. And because `IntentService` is always in another thread, I don´t know why there is this kind of problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Android will kill a Service that's currently working only when there's a severe shortage of memory, which is pretty unusual. So I don't think you have to worry about this.

Comment: Is it killing your service while your application is running or only when the user is not using your app, because in the second situation, it's not a good practice to make a long running process while the user is not using your app.

Comment: I use intent service to save some data to the database, until the operation is stopped by user. I want to secure the IntentService in case there is incoming call etc. I found out this problem accidentaly, when the IntentService was running and I received the message and a call in the same time. I have dual core, so it surprised me.

Comment: If you want to make sure that your service won't be stopped you need to use `startForeground()`, but in this case you need to specify notification. Check the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29

Comment: What device are you running this on when you see this behaviour?

Comment: Xperia S, Dual Core, 1GB RAM